# How to find interval of convergence for a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the interval of convergence for the given power series. 
$\sum \cfrac{(x−4)^n}{n(−7)^n}$

The series is convergent between what x values?

Comment: I tried the Ratio Test to test for convergence. By the Ratio Test, this series is absolutely convergent. However, my x-values are not accepted. I thought the interval would be [11,-3)

Comment: Please show the work you went through to get $[11, -3)$ and then we could help you pinpoint the mistake.

Comment: Using the Ratio Test, I evaluated (a_n+1/a_n). Which was, (((x-4^n+1)/(n+1)(-7^n+1)) * ((n(-7)^n)/((x-4)^n))). Which I simplified to x-4/-7 as n approaches infinity. Due to absolute convergence, I said x-4/-7 is greater than -1 but less than 1.

Comment: (1) Everything you wrote in the comment above should be added into your original post, and preferably formatted well with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). (2) The Ratio Test doesn't work that way, because it must be applied to absolute values of the terms of the series. (3) Do you see anything strange with the interval $[11,-3)$?